# Bash grep command finding the same file 5 times

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ubuntu-14.04

I'm building a little bash script to run another bash script that's found in multiple directories. Here's the code:

```
cd /home/mainuser/CaseStudies/

grep -R -o --include="Auto.sh" [\w] | wc -l
```

When I execute just that part, it finds the same file 5 times in each folder. So instead of getting 49 results, I get 245. I've written a recursive bash script before and I used it as a template for this problem:

```
grep -R -o --include=*.class [\w] | wc -l
```

This code has always worked perfectly, without any duplication. I've tried running the first code with and without the " ", I've tried -r as well. I've read through the bash documentation and I can't seem to find a way to prevent, or even why I'm getting, this duplication. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

As a separate, but related question, if I could launch Auto.sh inside of each directory so that the output of Auto.sh was dumped into that directory; without having to place Auto.sh in each folder. That would probably be much more efficient that what I'm currently doing and it would also probably fix my current duplication problem.

This is the code for Auto.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash          
index=1
cd /home/mainuser/CaseStudies/
grep -R -o --include=*.class [\w] | wc -l
grep -R -o --include=*.class [\w] |awk '{print $3}' > out.txt

while read LINE; do
    echo 'Path '$LINE > 'Outputs/ClassOut'$index'.txt'
    javap -c $LINE >> 'Outputs/ClassOut'$index'.txt'
    index=$((index+1))
done <out.txt
```

Preferably I would like to make it dump only the javap outputs for the application its currently looking at. Since those .class files could be in any number of sub-directories, I'm not sure how to make them all dump in the top folder, without executing a modified Auto.sh in the top directory of each application.

Comment: Try quoting the `'[\w]'` pattern? Also, if `Auto.sh` writes its output to the current directory then yes, you almost certainly can avoid having 49 copies of the file. Just `pushd $dir; /abs/path/to/Auto.sh; popd` in a loop over the directories.

Comment: Adding ' ' is has increased the number to 343. Which means its now finding two extra entries in each directory. I should have been more specific with my second question. Auto.sh goes through every sub-directory and performs a javap function on each .class file found. It currently outputs everything to one folder, but I would like to break up that output by application. So I would want to execute it in the top directory for the application and output all of the javap information for that application to a single folder in the top directory of the application. I can post the Auto.sh code above.

Comment: `-o` will print out each match, so are you sure the pattern isn't legitimately matching 5 times? if you just want to know which files have matches you could do `-l` instead of `-o`

Comment: -l worked! Thank you both so much! Any further suggestion on how to get Auto.sh to execute as described in my above comment? I'm going to add the code for Auto.sh to the original question. Thanks again.

Comment: The value of `$LINE` is the "name" of a java class? Locatable at that name-to-path location from the current directory? And you want the output of each run of `javap` to go where relative to the current directory and the class it is being run on?

Comment: Yes $LINE is the path of each .class file. It iterates through the paths from the grep command above. So I would like to output each run of javap for the entire application that is currently targeted into one folder. So that I have all of the javap information for that application in one folder. I added a better description above with the code for Auto.sh.

Comment: Instead of running `grep` twice, just use `wc -l out.txt` to output the count.

Comment: What do you  believe the pattern `[\w]` is matching? As I read it, it matches the letter `w`, exactly the same as if you had used the pattern `w`.

Comment: I think I might have accidentally carried that over as a javaism. I was just trying to see if it would match anything. I guess I should probably remove that.

Comment: @TheNoviceAllen: Since the shell interprets the argument even before grep sees it, the backslash will be removed leaving grep with `[w]`. But even if you escape the backslash or quote the argument, grep won't treat `\w` as though it were `[[:alnum:]]`, which I *think* is what you were looking for. For grep, `[\w]` is a character class which recognizes either a backslash or the letter w.

Comment: I replaced it with `'\w'` which now just seems to be looking for files of that name containing any words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to fix the multiple find:

```
grep -R -o --include="Auto.sh" [\w] | wc -l
```

Should be:

```
grep -R -l --include=Auto.sh '\w' | wc -l
```

The reason this was happening, was that it was looking for instances of the letter w in Auto.sh. Which occurred 5 times in the file.

However, the overall fix that doesn't require having to place Auto.sh in every directory, is something like this:

```
MAIN_DIR=/home/mainuser/CaseStudies/

cd $MAIN_DIR

ls -d */ > DirectoryList.txt

while read LINE; do
    cd $LINE
    mkdir ProjectOutputs
    bash /home/mainuser/Auto.sh
    cd $MAIN_DIR
done <DirectoryList.txt
```

That calls this Auto.sh code:

```
index=1

grep -R -o --include=*.class '\w' | wc -l
grep -R -o --include=*.class '\w' | awk '{print $3}' > ProjectOutputs.txt

while read LINE; do
    echo 'Path '$LINE > 'ProjectOutputs/ClassOut'$index'.txt'
    javap -c $LINE >> 'ProjectOutputs/ClassOut'$index'.txt'
    index=$((index+1))
done <ProjectOutputs.txt
```

Thanks again for everyone's help!